# USCG PSIX Web Service returning auth error

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, soap

The United States Coast Guard runs a SOAP Web Service called PSIX:

- https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/default.aspx
- https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx
- https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx?WSDL

Recently some software that has been accessing this web service for a ling time started erroring out, the error returned from PSIX is:
`The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.`

There is a problem with the certificate on the site, but that's been like that for as long as we've been accessing the service (a little over a year and a half).

There is no mention on the USCG sites that I can find saying you need any kind of authentication to access the service - so I'm not sure what to do.  There are also no contact details provided for the service I can find to ask if they've changed something on their side - there is comment form to which I've submitted a question about this issue.

The service was added into a .NET Core project using the `Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider`.  We create an instance if it with this static helper method.

Any ideas on how to get around the error?

```
private static PSIXDataSoap ServiceProxy
{
    get {
        try
        {
            if (_serviceProxy == null)
            {
                BasicHttpBinding binding = null;
                binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport); //Force use SSL, otherwise you get "expected http"

                binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000;
                binding.MaxBufferSize = 20000000;
                binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 20000000;
                binding.AllowCookies = true;

                var factory = new ChannelFactory<PSIXDataSoap>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://psix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx"));

                //Tell it: Yes, I know the Coast Guard's Certificate is invalid...
                factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
                    new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
                    {
                        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
                        RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
                    };

                _serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            }

            return _serviceProxy;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And then access the proxy like:

```
var psixResponse = await ServiceProxy.getVesselSummaryAsync(vesselId_str, vesselName_str, callsign_str, vin_str, hin_str, flag_str, service_str, buildYear_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code work great.  If it fails on your machine then it is probably a TLS issue. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx?WSDL";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can retrieve the WSDL too, but trying to run any operation, like `getVesselSummaryAsync` results in the error.

Comment: Why do you need to access the proxy when you have the results.  Just need to parse the xml results.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the lines I guess the USCG changed the URL of their web service.  So I:

- Deleted and re-added the WCF Connected Service reference
- Changed my service proxy helper method to use the new URL (I think this was the root cause of my problem).

As to why I needed to have the special helper method instead of creating the service reference from the built-in initializer, I think mainly because:

- I needed to bypass the certificate error
- I needed to increase the default message/buffer sizes because some of these calls can return *a lot* of information.

Anyway, new helper method that fixed my problem:

```
private static PSIXDataSoap ServiceProxy
{
    get {
        try
        {
            if (_serviceProxy == null)
            {
                BasicHttpBinding binding = null;
                binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport); //Force use SSL, otherwise you get "expected http"

                binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000;
                binding.MaxBufferSize = 20000000;
                binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 20000000;
                binding.AllowCookies = true;

                //var factory = new ChannelFactory<PSIXDataSoap>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://psix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx"));
                var factory = new ChannelFactory<PSIXDataSoap>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx")); //<--- NEW URL
                //Tell it: Yes, I know the Coast Guard's Certificate is invalid...
                factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
                    new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
                    {
                        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
                        RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
                    };

                _serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            }

            return _serviceProxy;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```